# Android - Upload Large image to server

Tags: android

I am trying to have my application upload images to the webserver using the code below. It works sometimes, but also seems to fail with a memory error. Can someone please post an example of how to accomplish this if the file size is to big? Also, I am building this to support 1.5 and up. I don't mind if the code given to me resizes the image smaller before upload.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);

File file = new File(nameOfFile);

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(fileInputStream, file.length());

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

if (responseEntity != null) {
    responseEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: It seems when the memory issue occurs the resulting image is not complete. Meaning it has gray pixels below it where it failed.

Comment: Did you found a solution for the problem ? @BBCM

Answer (score 1):

You have two option to make your code workable.

1. You should use multi part approach to upload larger size file. Which i am using in my code. 
   [Its Apache code](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/multipartpost.html). (Yes, you can easily port it in your Android project).
2. You can minimize the image resolution. by using SampleSize flag,
   Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) link.

I hope it help.

Comment: Can you post an example code for the 2nd solution. I rather do this because I resize it anyway once it hits my server. Thank you very much for your fast response.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code for uploading images.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

MultipartEntity multiPart = new MultipartEntity();
multiPart.addPart("my_picture", new FileBody(new File(IMG_URL)));

httpPost.setEntity(multiPart);
HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should really look into setChunkedStreamingMode of the connection. or, indeed, use MultipartEntity (it's apache httpcomponents library - you will easily find lots of solutions on this.

as for resizing images, it's quite simple:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2; // look at the link Rajnikant gave for more details on this
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
// here you save your bitmap to whatever you want
```

but it is memory consuming too...

Comment: inSampleSize makes original picture small, but what if picture is already small. Every Android phone takes different size of pictures, low end phones take already small pictures. Is there any good way to handle that instead of using inSampleSize.